# Sum of two Gaussian PDFs

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution, density-function

I want to find the sum of two univariate Gaussians with different variances.
Considering that the sum of two independent normal variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ gives$$X_1+X_2\sim \operatorname{N}\left (\mu _1+\mu _2, \sigma _1^2+\sigma _2^2\right ),$$then I would expect that the sum of their PDFs is another Gaussian PDF. That is $G_{\sigma _1^2+\sigma _2^2}(x)$. Is that the case? What happens if they are independent?

Comment: Do you really want the sum of PDF's (and not the PDF of the sum)? A sum of two PDF's is itself not a PDF.

Comment: Sum of two pdfs integrated over the reals, sums to 2. Therefore it cannot be a pdf.

Comment: Yes that's right @drhab, only the sum of the PDFs. Ok, then sums of any PDFs is not relying on the properties of the PDF of a sum of random variables.

Comment: @RahulMadhavan Ok that makes sense.

Comment: If $X_1$ has PDF $f$ and $X_2$ has PDF $g$ then the sum of the PDF's is $f+g$ (which is of course not a PDF). So such a sum is utterly direct, but it is quite useless. There are no "nice" alternative expressions for that sum (if that was what you were hoping or looking for).

Answer (score 1):

PDFs must integrate 1, so the sum of two PDFs integrates 2 (it cannot be a PDF). Your question is linked to random variable mixtures, where you define a random variable whose PDF is the convex combination of the original PDFs. For example the average of two normals is a mixture of normals (two bells).

I recommend you read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution#Two_normal_distributions

Answer (score 1):

The p.d.f. $f_Z$ of the sum of 2 normal random variables $Z=X+Y$ is computed by *convolving* $f_X$ with $f_Y$, or $f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)f_Y(z-x)dx$. It is not computed by taking the average of $f_X$ with $f_Y$.

As Matías mentioned, the average of the 2 Gaussian p.d.f.'s is a mixture model, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution#Mixture_of_two_normal_distributions). To interpret $Z$, consider flipping a fair coin and set $Z=X$ if the coin lands on head and set $Z=Y$ if it lands on tail. In this way, $Z$ is $X$ half the time and is $Y$ half the time, so $f_Z$ is the the average of $f_X$ with $f_Y$. Therefore, $F_Z$ is the the average of $F_X$ with $F_Y$. See charts below.

[image: Averaging N(0,1) and N(0,4).]

We can generalize by assuming $Z$ takes $X$ with probability $d$ and $Y$ with probability $1-d$. We can change the means and variances of $X$ and $Y$ to make them sufficiently far away and exhibit bimodality.

[image: Mixing X=N(-2,1) and Y=N(2,4) with d=0.3.]

Code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_context("paper")
sns.set_style("darkgrid")
plt.rcParams['patch.edgecolor'] = 'none'

def normalPdf(x, mean, variance):
    return (1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*variance))*np.exp(-0.5*(x-mean)**2/variance)

def normalCdf(x, mean, variance):
    pdf = normalPdf(x, mean, variance)
    return np.cumsum(pdf)/np.sum(pdf)

# gaussian specification
mean1, variance1 = -2, 1
mean2, variance2 = 2, 4
d = 0.3

# sample data points
N = 100000
x = np.linspace(-7.5, 7.5, 100)
X = mean1 + np.sqrt(variance1) * np.random.randn(N)
Y = mean2 + np.sqrt(variance2) * np.random.randn(N)
Z = np.random.rand(N) < d
Z = Z*X + (1-Z)*Y

# plot
fg, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True, figsize=(6, 8), dpi=80)
ax[0].hist(Z, bins=int(N/100), density=True, alpha=0.3, label="empirical")
ax[0].plot(x, normalPdf(x, mean1, variance1), label="$\hat{f_X}(x)$")
ax[0].plot(x, normalPdf(x, mean2, variance2), label="$\hat{f_Y}(x)$")
ax[0].plot(x, d*normalPdf(x, mean1, variance1)+(1-d)*normalPdf(x, mean2, variance2), label="$\hat{f_Z}(x)$", ls="-.")
ax[0].legend()
ax[0].set_ylabel("Probability Density Function")
ax[1].hist(Z, bins=int(N/100), density=True, alpha=0.3, label="empirical", cumulative=True)
ax[1].plot(x, normalCdf(x, mean1, variance1), label="$\hat{f_X}(x)$")
ax[1].plot(x, normalCdf(x, mean2, variance2), label="$\hat{f_Y}(x)$")
ax[1].plot(x, d*normalCdf(x, mean1, variance1)+(1-d)*normalCdf(x, mean2, variance2), label="$\hat{f_Z}(x)$", ls="-.")
ax[1].legend()
ax[1].set_ylabel("Cumulative Density Function")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your code is returning floats, you don't want irrational results. You can use comprehension to plot this in one argument. Ideally you want to reduce the lines in the code and use proper UTF-8 formatting so it's easier to read